# умножение матрицы А на матрицу В

Tags: c++, память, матрицы

при вводе отрицательных элементов матрицы программа выдаёт ошибку. В чем проблема?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    int** A, n, m, q;
    cout << "Enter cols count in matrix A and rows count in matrix B: "; //столбцы матрицы А и строки матрицы В
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Enter rows count in matrix A: "; //строки матрицы А
    cin >> m;
    cout << "Enter cols count in matrix B: "; //столбцы матрицы В
    cin >> q;
        
    A = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * m);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        A[i] = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            cin >> A[i][j];
        }
    }


    int** B;
    B = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * n);
    for (int i = 0; i < q; ++i)
        B[i] = (int*)malloc(q * sizeof(int));

    cout << "enter the matrix B: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < q; ++j) {
            cin >> B[i][j];
        }
    }


    int** C;
    C = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * m);
    for (int i = 0; i < q; ++i)
        C[i] = (int*)malloc(q * sizeof(int));



    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < q; ++j) {
            for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
                C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "\nMatrix A: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            cout << setw(5) << A[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "\nMatrix B: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < q; ++j) {
            cout << setw(5) << B[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "\nMatrix C: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < q; ++j) {
            cout << setw(5) << C[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
        free(A[i]);
    free(A);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        free(B[i]);
    free(B);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
        free(C[i]);
    free(C);
    

    return 0;
}
```

вот ошибка, которая возникает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а в чем вопрос-то?

Comment: при вводе отрицательных элементов матрицы у меня программа выдаёт ошибку. как это можно исправить?

Comment: Для начала проблема в том, что матрица `C` содержит мусор. Либо явно присвойте её элементам нулевые значения, либо используйте `calloc()` вместо `malloc()` в `C[i] = (int*)malloc(q * sizeof(int));`

Comment: тоесть должно быть так: `int** C;
 C = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * m);
 for (int i = 0; i < q; ++i)
  C[i] = (int*)calloc(q * sizeof(int));`?

Comment: Нет, у `calloc()` размер задается по-другому: `C[i] = (int*)calloc(q , sizeof(int));`

Comment: ага, понял. я заполнил матрицу С нулями, а дальше что нужно сделать?

Comment: Если ошибка все еще присутствует, то тогда искать ее (было бы хорошо, если бы Вы приложили к вопросу тестовые данные, при которых возникает ошибка).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас вот такой код:

```
B = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * n);
for (int i = 0; i < q; ++i)
    B[i] = (int*)malloc(q * sizeof(int));
```

Т.е. вы выделили в `B` место для `n` указателей, но присваиваете `q` из них. И если `q` больше `n`, то вы просто вылетаете за границы выделенной памяти.

Будьте внимательнее!